# MySQL connector 6.7.4 and Entity Framework 5 exceptions

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, entity-framework

I downloaded [MySQL Connector/Net 6.7.4](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/) and [MySQL for Visual Studio 1.0.2](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/installer/), and then followed [these instructions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj206878) to test it:

1. Create a connection to the existing MySQL database.
2. Create a console application.
3. Add the *ADO.NET Entity Data Model* from the existing database connection.
4. Add Code Generation Item *EF 5.x DbContext Generator*, replacing the .tt files.
5. Write some code that retrieved records from the database.

Running the application, I got this exception:

> **ConfigurationErrorsException**: Failed to find or load the registered .Net Framework Data Provider.

Then I added references to the `MySql.Data` and `MySql.Data.Entity` libraries version 6.7.4.0 to my .NET 4.5 project. Now when I run the application, I get a different exception:

> **FileLoadException**: Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data, Version=6.6.5.0,culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Note the version number, which is not the version of MySQL Connector that I have installed.

How do I get it working correctly?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The trick to solving this was:

1. Add references to the `MySql.Data` and `MySql.Data.Entity` libraries of the correct version (6.7.4.0 for .NET 4.5, in my case) to the project.
2. Edit `machine.config` with your editor run as administrator, and replace all occurences of MySQL version `6.6.5.0` by `6.7.4.0`.

For the second step, note that there are multiple `machine.config` files, one for each framework version (3.0, 3.5, 4.0) and architecture (32-bit, 64-bit). Also note that the `machine.config` file for .NET 4.5 is in the .NET 4.0 folder. You can find the `machine.config` files in:

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\\Config

And:

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\\Config

If there are no references to MySQL in the `machine.config` file, you might not have installed [MySQL for Visual Studio](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/installer/). Either do that, or add the following to the `app.config` file of your project:

```
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
        <add name="MySQL Data Provider"
            invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
            description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL"
            type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.7.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

Note however, that when you both install `MySQL for Visual Studio` *and* add the above snippet to your `app.config` file, then you'll get this exception:

> **ConfigurationErrorsException**: Column 'InvariantName' is constrained to be unique. Value 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient' is already present.

Comment: Changing the version to '6.7.4.0' worked in the machine.config.  This must be an installer bug, as 6.7.4 was installed on a fresh installation of Windows, but the reference to 6.5.5 was still written to the machine.config.

Answer (score 6):

I don't like to edit machine.config. Just add this redirect to web.config:

```
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="MySql.Data" publicKeyToken="c5687fc88969c44d" culture="neutral" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.6.5.0" newVersion="6.7.4.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Answer (score 5):

Using this should stop the exception that Virtlink mentioned:

```
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
        <remove name="MySQL Data Provider" />
        <add name="MySQL Data Provider"
            invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
            description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL"
            type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.7.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

Especially note the `<remove name="MySQL Data Provider" />` line.

Comment: Please explain how this stops the exception.

Comment: @rgettman It removes the existing configuration for MySQL Data Provider before adding the new one, so there is no complaint regarding duplicate entries.

Comment: In my case I had to replace `<remove name="MySQL Data Provider" />` with `<remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>`

Answer (score 1):

Download MYSQL 6.7.4.0 from [HERE](http://download.softagency.net/MySQL/Downloads/Connector-Net/) . Notice that your specific problem requires 6.7.4.0 and NOT other version !

Direct link is [this](http://download.softagency.net/MySQL/Downloads/Connector-Net/mysql-connector-net-6.7.4-noinstall.zip) .

Download and add the files to the reference folder of your solution .

This would probably solve your problem (it did for me , and yes , I know this can by a very annoying problem) .

Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

I realise this thread had an answer back in 2013 but I have just encountered this problem again.  In my situation, I recently installed the Windows 10 Anniversary update.  Didn't have an issue before this.

As per the answers above, it turns out my Machine.config file had been overwritten (I presume by the update).

For me once I restored the MySql Assembly information to the Machine.config file, it immediately started working again.

In particular the "Runtime" and "DbProviderFactories" sections had been wiped and had to be replaced.  They were as follows (these will vary depending on the versions of the assemblies you are using):

**Runtime Section:**

> ```
> <runtime>
>    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
>    <dependentAssembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
>        <assemblyIdentity name="MySql.Data" publicKeyToken="c5687fc88969c44d" culture="neutral" />
>        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="6.7.4.0" newVersion="6.9.9.0" />
>    </dependentAssembly>
>    <dependentAssembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
>        <assemblyIdentity name="MySql.Data.Entity" publicKeyToken="c5687fc88969c44d" culture="neutral" />
>        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="6.7.4.0" newVersion="6.9.9.0" />
>    </dependentAssembly>
>    <dependentAssembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
>        <assemblyIdentity name="MySql.Web" publicKeyToken="c5687fc88969c44d" culture="neutral" />
>        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="6.7.4.0" newVersion="6.9.9.0" />
>    </dependentAssembly>
>    </assemblyBinding>
> </runtime>
> ```

**DbProviderFactories Section**

> ```
> <DbProviderFactories>
>        <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.9.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
> </DbProviderFactories>
> ```

Hope this helps anyone else coming across the same problem.