# Failed to generate code. Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data, Version=6.6.5.0

Tags: mysql, asp.net, reference

I'm getting the following error on all of my website's pages:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Parser Error

Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Failed to generate code. Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data, Version=6.6.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Source Error: 


Line 1:  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
Line 2:  <xs:schema id="newsarticles" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/news.xsd" xmlns:mstns="http://tempuri.org/news.xsd" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/news.xsd" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:msprop="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msprop" attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified">
Line 3:    <xs:annotation>

Source File: /App_Code/news.xsd    Line: 1 

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'MySql.Data, Version=6.6.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' could not be loaded.
```

I checked the assemblies in my web.config, but no references to MySQL are there:

```
    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.0">
        <assemblies>
    <clear />
    <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
            <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
            <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
            <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
            <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
            <add assembly="System.Data.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
            <add assembly="System.Data.Services.Client, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" /></assemblies>
    </compilation>
```

I then checked the references of my website project. There I noticed a lot of different MySQL versions are referenced. I tried to delete all references but version 6.7.4.0, however, I can't even delete the references (see screenshot).
[image]

I have these files in my bin folder, both of version 6.7.4.0:

`MySql.Data.dll` and `MySql.Data.Entity.dll`

How to fix this error?

Comment: Possible duplicate (or related): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18882217/mysql-connector-6-7-4-and-entity-framework-5-exceptions

Answer (score 1):

try to add this to your web.config:

```
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
      <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description="Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
```

Also, you don't need to reference any dlls from GAC. Just use nuget packages (MySQL.Data, MySQL.Web)