# Using MariaDB with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, mariadb

Recently, I read a news that MariaDB is a drop-off replacement for MySQL since [MySQL has unfriendly pricing for clustered/enterprise version](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2013/09/12/google_mariadb_mysql_migration/) according to Google.

Now I can't find anything relevant about EF for MariaDB on Google so I'm hoping someone knows about it. Is it ok to use [MySQL driver for this since it is 100% compatible](http://www.skysql.com/content/mariadb-100-compatible-open-source-drop-replacement-mysql-database)? Any thoughts?

**Update**

I just found out that [RedHat is also switching from MySQL to MariaDB](http://www.zdnet.com/red-hat-will-switch-from-oracle-mysql-to-mariadb-reports-7000017907/) for it's default database management system. So it is necessary for my current project to switch it to MariaDB.

Comment: Seeing as MariaDB is a political fork, they'd be insane to break compatibility with MySQL's wire protocol though. It's probably easier to maintain compatibility than maintain an entire family of client software. They also expressly say this in the docs: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-versus-mysql-compatibility/.

Comment: I don't have the resources to virtualized a RedHat server with MariaDB. What I have tried is a MySQL on a RedHat server.

Comment: You can't download VirtualBox, install CentOS, and MariaDB into that, and point a sample project at that DB?

Comment: Good idea but I can't with my machine's specs. And that is not what I'm asking for.

Comment: Well it's something that will have to be done anyway. Nonetheless, seeing how their docs expressly say that "mid-level" interfaces (i.e. published APIs, not data file formats and internal stuff) are compatible, the high level ones really should be as well. EF breaking would be a bug.

Comment: try http://brice-lambson.blogspot.in/2012/10/entity-framework-on-mysql.html

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I was able to use MariaDB 10 with Entity Framework although it required a bit of work mainly because the MySQL tools are a bit buggy.

To work with MySQL/MariaDB in Visual Studio **2010/2012**,you need to install [MySQL for Visual Studio](http://www.mysql.com/why-mysql/windows/visualstudio/) using [MySQL Installer](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/). I used the Web version as I only wanted to download the connectors and the extensions. Once you do this, you can add connections to MariaDB and create EF models.

This is not enough to run your code though. First you need to add the MySQL Connector using NuGet.

Unfortuanetly, MySQL for Visual Studio adds a reference to an older provider version (mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18882217/mysql-connector-6-7-4-and-entity-framework-5-exceptions)) and can't load the newer version. To fix this, I added the following section in my app.config:

```
<system.data>
   <DbProviderFactories>
     <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
     <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" 
           description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" 
           type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.7.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
   </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

This replaces the old reference with a new one. Note that I used

```
<remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
```

not

```
<remove name="MySql Data Provider"/>
```

in the `remove` element.

Currently, MySQL for Visual Studio isn't supported in Visual Studio 2013

**UPDATE - 2017**

Connector/.NET is essentially stagnant, with the same problems it had in 2013, eg no true asynchronous calls. The "async" calls are fake - they are run on separate threads, defeating the very purpose of using `async`. That alone makes it unsuitable for web applications, where one wants to server as many requests as possible using the *minimum* number of threads/CPU.

Never mind about .NET Core support.

That's why in the past few years people have built their own, truly asynchronous providers. Some of the more popular ones are:

- [MySqlConnector](https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector) offers a truly asynchronous provider for .NET *and* .NET Core
- [Pomelo](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql) offers EF Core support on top of MySQLConnector

With about 100K NuGet downloads each, frequent versions and active maintenance.

They aren't "official", but definitely worth trying

**Lockdown Update - April 2020**

It seems MySqlConnector and Pomelo have really taken off.

Connector/.NET finally released [a couple of versions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data/) after almost two years with the latest, 8.0.19, getting **233K** downloads.

[MySqlConnector](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/) on the other hand, got **496K** downloads for version 0.61.0. Minor updates are frequent, with the latest, 0.63.2 coming 8 hours before this post. That's probably a bit too frequent, but far better than 2 years.

I haven't checked features or MySql 8 compatibility yet. If I had to chose though (which I will probably do for a project next week), I'd start with MySqlConnector.

I suspect Connector/.NET will be forced to offer far more frequent updates going on, to keep pace with .NET Core releases, but that's just speculation at this point.

Comment: There is some kind of support now (VS2013 & MySQL), but it's a pain. I ended up creating EF with 2012, and then using 2013 for development.

Comment: And then you have a GPL-application, btw. - if you don't have a commercial license for the GPL (not LGPL) MySQL connector.

Comment: @StefanSteiger the "official" connector has so many serious problems (eg fake async calls) that people started their own projects in the last 3 years. [MySqlConnector](https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector)
seems to be the most popular ADO.NET provider and [Pomelo](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql) offers EF support on top of it. It looks like *Oracle* doesn't care that much about MySQL (for .NET I mean)

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos: I would use the mariadb-connector instead, works for MySQL as well: https://github.com/noahvans/mariadb-connector-net  But interesting via Pomelo if you use EF.

Comment: @StefanSteiger it looks abandoned. The last commit was 2 years ago and the last build failed

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos: Yea, just noticed that too. MySqlConnector then. Might be a modified version of an old version of MySqlConnector, but that's just a guess.

Comment: Three years later, and it seems that things have changed and updated. A possible update to this answer? :)

Comment: @FireController1847 the real difference is that MySqlConnector and Pomelo now have almost as many if not more downloads per month in NuGet as MySql.Data, but far more frequent updates.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the update. Yeah, I ended up using those and I finally managed to get a working version of everything, even if it wasn't quite as fluid as everything else .NET :P