# Not able to add MySql to Entity Framework

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I want to add add MySql to my Entity Framework. I have already added MySql.Data.ddl & MySql.Data.Entity.EF6 as project reference. And also made changes in web.config as below

```
<entityFramework codeConfigurationType="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration, MySql.Data.Entity">
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity" /> 
    <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=6.8.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"></provider></providers>
  </entityFramework>
```

Also I have Rebuild Solution & Restarted Visual Studio still I can't see MySQL option Entity Framework as you can see in below screenshot.

[image]

Comment: try the answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20183781/using-mariadb-with-entity-framework).

Comment: You have to install the DDEX provider that is included with MySQL full installation. Installing the EF provider is not enough.