# Could not load file or assembly 'mysql.data,' version=6.7.4.0

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2012

I know that this problem has been encountered by many users here on SO but I cannot seem to find a permanent solution.

I keep encountering the error `"could not load file or assembly 'mysql.data,' version=6.7.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"`.

I am using Visual Studio 2012 Version 11.0.61030.00 Update 4. I have installed MySQL version 5.6.15.0 for Visual Studio. After installation, I notice that the machine.config file for both the 32 and 64 bit entries show Version=6.6.5.0 even though I have never installed a MySQL of that version.

I then check the project references for MySql.Data and MySql.Data.Entity and they are the correct version, i.e. 6.7.4.0 and copy local property set to true.

I even copy this to my App.config file:

```
 <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <clear />
      <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.7.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
```

My application .NET 4.5 will run fine until I shut down my computer. If I work on my machine for 4 days without switching it off no problem.
After I shut down and restart my machine, the error comes up. I then try to manually change the machine.config settings to the version 6.7.4.0 but to no avail. I try to change the project configuration settings from any CPU to x86 but no solution.

When I encounter this, the only way I get to fix this is to uninstall MySQl and reinstall it again.

Is there a permanent solution to this problem? I have tried this [MySQL connector 6.7.4 and Entity Framework 5 exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18882217/mysql-connector-6-7-4-and-entity-framework-5-exceptions) but like I say it seems a temporary solution.

Answer (score 0):

I could be off on this but you could change the references specific version value to `false`.

`Right click on the reference > Select Properties > Change the Specific version value`